# How many games must a team win to raise its winning percentage from $50\%$ to $60\%$ after playing $60$ games?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A baseball team has won 50% of the 60 games it has played. Find the number of games the team must win in succession to increase it's winning percentage to 60%

Please show all work.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you tried anything? Regards

Answer (score 3):

This is not a probability question. But, given that they won 50% of 60 games, they won 30 games. What would be winning percentage if they win $n$ more games in succession? $30+n$ won games out of $60+n$ games played, hence the winning percentage will be $\frac{30+n}{60+n}$. You want this ratio to be equal to 60%, or $\frac{60}{100}$. Solving that equation, you get $n=15$.